# Beaglebone black freeze at "reading u-boot.img" stage

Tags: qt, beagleboneblack, yocto, u-boot

I am building boot2qt image for beaglebone black (BBB) using Yocto. I made the following steps:

**Notes**: I debug BBB via serial cable and my host is Ubuntu 16.04LTS x64

- using poky-morty-16.0.1 (download from download-homepage of yocto project)
- download meta-b2qt from layer http://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-boot2qt.git/ to poky-morty-16.0.1
- follow to http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-custom-embedded-linux-image.html

My build was successful. But when I wrote b2qt-embedded-qt5-image-beaglebone.img to sdcard, and then plug-in into beagblebone black board.
- press "S2" button on board, then power on

Beaglebone black stuck and boot unsuccessfully

On screen it only show some lines of message as follow:
" U-Boot SPL 2017.01-g8369eec4f3 (Apr 15 2017 - 05:09:59)
Trying to boot from MMC1
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

reading u-boot.img
reading u-boot.img "
Please show me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

A CRC error indicates that some data in your image file is damaged. Try to write your image again to the sdcard and see if this can solve the problem.
I encountered this problem a lot burning my images with dd and re-writing them often solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried too much but it could not solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the .wic image instead of the .img?

Comment: That CRC message is typically benign (it's only a warning rather than an error), and probably provides no clue to the OP's issue. That CRC warning message pertains only to the (probably uninitialized rather than corrupted) environment area which is separate from any code image, and U-Boot can fully cope with that situation (assuming that the default environment in U-Boot is properly configured for this board).  *"...re-writing them often solved the issue"* -- Then something else was going on, and you're just presenting a cargo-cult solution.  A `saveenv` command should eliminate that warning.

Comment: I use this command "bitbake b2qt-embedded-qt5-image" to build b2qt-image. Among the built images was not .wic image. Please show me how to create *.wic image.

Comment: I'm sorry. The image format depend on the recipes. I thought that it generated the .wic automatically. I think you should follow sawdust 's suggestion.
@sawdust I'm sorry... I thought it would be helpful... I'll show myself out.

Comment: "bitbake b2qt-embedded-qt5-image" don't create *.wic image automatically. I tried adding "IMAGE_FSTYPES += "wic"" to local.conf to create *.wic image. Regardless to that all of output image still don't include *.wic image. Please show me how to create *.wic image. Thanks